# Find the average power dissipation of the load

Tags: circuit-analysis, waveform

I have given the following voltage and current waveforms.

[image]

I am required to find the average power dissipation of the load.

I know \$ P_{avg} = \frac {\int_0^T \mathrm{v}\mathrm{i}\,\mathrm{d}t}{T} \$

I have trouble finding the equations for the waveforms.
Please anyone help. 
(Is there any other that is easier to find the average power ?)

Comment: If i told you it was \$\dfrac{V_M\cdot I_M}{4}\$ would it help you?

Comment: Graphically multiply both curves together: some parts are zero and some parts ramp up or ramp down. Determine the average value (determine the non-zero areas) over a switching period and you are done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, because the function is periodic with period \$\text{T}\$, so \$\text{P}\left(t+\text{T}\right)=\text{P}\left(t\right)\$, we know that the average is given by:

$$\overline{\text{P}}=\frac{1}{\text{T}}\int_0^\text{T}\text{P}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\tag1$$

Where:

$$\text{P}\left(t\right)=\text{V}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{I}\left(t\right)\tag2$$

Using your pictures we get:

$$\overline{\text{P}}=\frac{1}{\text{T}}\cdot\left\{\int_0^\frac{\text{T}}{2}\text{P}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t+\int_\frac{\text{T}}{2}^\text{T}\text{P}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\right\}=$$
$$\frac{1}{\text{T}}\cdot\left\{\int_0^\frac{\text{T}}{4}\text{P}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t+\int_\frac{\text{T}}{4}^\frac{\text{T}}{2}\text{P}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t+\int_\frac{\text{T}}{2}^\frac{3\text{T}}{4}\text{P}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t+\int_\frac{3\text{T}}{4}^\text{T}\text{P}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\right\}=$$
$$\frac{1}{\text{T}}\cdot\left\{0+\int_\frac{\text{T}}{4}^\frac{\text{T}}{2}\text{P}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t+\int_\frac{\text{T}}{2}^\frac{3\text{T}}{4}\text{P}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t+0\right\}=$$
$$\frac{1}{\text{T}}\cdot\left\{\int_\frac{\text{T}}{4}^\frac{\text{T}}{2}\text{P}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t+\int_\frac{\text{T}}{2}^\frac{3\text{T}}{4}\text{P}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\right\}\tag3$$

Now, try to prove that:

$$\int_\frac{\text{T}}{4}^\frac{\text{T}}{2}\text{P}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t=\int_\frac{\text{T}}{2}^\frac{3\text{T}}{4}\text{P}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t=\frac{\text{V}_\text{m}\text{I}_\text{m}\text{T}}{8}\tag4$$

Which gives:

$$\overline{\text{P}}=\frac{1}{\text{T}}\cdot\left\{\frac{\text{V}_\text{m}\text{I}_\text{m}\text{T}}{8}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{m}\text{I}_\text{m}\text{T}}{8}\right\}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{m}\text{I}_\text{m}}{4}\tag5$$

Comment: That's not a hint -1.

Comment: @Andyaka In university, I had to prove these kinds of things so I did not show how I derived the integrals. Anyway thanks for the -1

Comment: In that case, all you've done is come up with the same "hint" as I did (as a comment under the question) but using a method that took at least ten minutes longer than me and misses the whole point of solving the problem visually. In other words you are discouraging the OP from using their eyes and brain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate the equations, however you can integrate different portions of one cycle separately. For example, t=0 to t=T/4, t=0 to t= T/2, and then sum them. The integral of sums is equal to the sum of integrals.

The equation for a straight line should not be a problem for you to write.

Answer (score 0):

Calculus way:
To use that average power equation, it best to split it up into a sum of integrals over portions of time. 
As a hint, between t=0 and t=T/4, V=Vm. Between t=0 and t=T/4, I=0, as seen by the graph. integrating this over that time interval would give zero.

As a second hint, between t=T/4 and t=T/2, V=Vm. Between t=T/4 and t=T/2, I=a linear equation. To find a line for this portion, we simply use the line formula: y-y_0=m(x-x_0) where (x_0, y_0) is an initial point of line. m= is the slope. I’ll let you find the equation of this line.

As a third hint, since you are averaging over T, you only need to integrate from 0 to T.

Graphical way: 
Integrating a function in this case is the same as finding the “area under the curve”. Luckily your curves are linear and constant. As a good hint: the area of P=IV curve is same as area under I curve multiplied by the constant Vm or -Vm depending on where you are looking in graph. Well the area on some portions of your I curve is the area of a right angle triangle. I hope you remember how to find them area of a triangle.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

An answer has been accepted so here's my pictorial way of solving the problem i.e. use your eyes and some very simple arithmetic: -

[image]